# Proof of matrices are linear independent by taking trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For simplicity, given a set of $m \times n$ matrices, one can show their linear dependence by trying express a general $m \times n$ matrix in terms of given set of matrices as basis. For example:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&d\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&b\\c&0\end{pmatrix}$$

By inspection, it seems if two matrices are linear independent, it can be verified via $\mbox{Tr} \left( A^{T} B \right) = 0$.

I am not sure the validity of my inspection.

Comment: Don't let the notation fool you, matrices are just vectors written in a rectangle instead of a column or row. You could just as easily ask if $(a,0,0,d)$ and $(0,b,c,0)$ are linearly independent to solidify your intuition. Your calculation of the trace shows that these matrices are orthogonal with respect to the inner product given by $\mbox{Tr}( A^TB)$.   This does imply linear independence as any set of mutually orthogonal vectors will be independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to consider two matrices, usually it is quite easy to say if they are linearly dependent or not, as $A$ and $B$ are linearly dependent if and only if there is a $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ such that
$$A=\lambda B\,.$$

Now, if $A$ and $B$ are linearly dependent, and both non-zero, then $A=\lambda B$, with $\lambda\neq 0$. So you have that
$$\mathrm{Tr}(A^TB) = \lambda^2 \mathrm{Tr}(B^TB)>0\,.$$
Indeed $\mathrm{Tr}(B^TB)$ is the sum of the squared eigenvalues of $B$, and hence it is positive, unless $B=0$.

So you can say that if both $A$ and $B$ are non-zero, then $\mathrm{Tr}(A^TB)=0$ implies that they are not linearly dependent (*i.e.*, they are linearly independent), as you conjectured.

On the other hand, the reverse is not true. You can easily find cases in which $\mathrm{Tr}(A^TB)\neq 0$, but $A$ and $B$ are linearly independent. For instance, let $A = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. Then $\mathrm{Tr}(A^TB) = 1\neq 0$, but clearly $A$ and $B$ are not linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

$Tr(A^TB)$ is the "standard" inner product for two matrices $A$ and $B$, if it is $0$ then it means that these two matrices are orthogonal for that inner product, and it is easy to show that the orthogonality implies linear independency. However this is not a necessary condition, only a sufficient condition. You can have two matrices such as $Tr(A^TB) \neq 0$ and $A,B$  independent.

Here it is easy to see that these two matrices are linearly independent because of the $0$ that are in different positions, i.e you can express them as the sums of different elementary matrices. You can also think of it a looking at the independency for two flat $4 \times 1$ column vectors.